# PlayProtect unknown developer warning - How to make developer known but without app in PlayStore

Tags: android, sideloading, google-play-protect

I want to distribute an Android app for **sideloading only**.
However, when users are installing this apk, PlayProtect shows a warning about *"...blocked... - unknown developer"*.

Is there a way, to register **myself as developer** / my signing keys with Google, but **without making my app known** to Google Play?

If yes, how do I sign my release to add such a "play developer certificate"?

(Goal is that PlayProtects warning may look like "We don't know this app, but at least the developer is known" which may sound less alarming for users than the current popup.)

Answer (score 2):

Upload the app to play store, go to store listings and disable all countries
except Vatican City or any small country (because at least 1 country needs to be checked)

Doing this will make your app available and recognised by play store but in reality only to 0.001% of world's population via google play :D

Comment: Sadly not an option in my case since I need to use the storage access functions that Google blocks since Android 11. So the App would be rejected. But this workaround may be an option for others. Thanks.